# how to select a button whose id contains a certain string?

Tags: jquery

How to select a button whose id contains a certain string? The reason I'm asking that is asp.net webform is adding the name of the container to the element's id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[submit]:addNewRow').click(function(){
    //Do someting...
    });      
});
```

The `id` of the button contains `AddNewRow`.

Thanks for helping

Comment: the `name` of the button is `AddNewRow` or the **id** of the button is `AddNewRow`? (there's a huge difference)

Comment: with ASP.NET webforms, you should be using classes. You can make them unique class names, but you should generally avoid selecting on IDs, due to the craziness of the autogenerated IDs.

Comment: You could pass the control's `ClientID` into the script and use that instead.

Comment: @scunliffe: I'm sorry. the id (not the name).

Comment: @Archer:  Never use ClientID before. That could be easier then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [attribute value contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). If the `id` contains "AddNewRow", that would be

```
$("[id*='AddNewRow']")
```